# Can I write a GWT application together with my normal Java application?

Tags: java, gwt

I already have an Java application running on client site.

This application currently does not have any UI. What it does is just transforming data for the client behind the scene.

We need to regularly upgrade the application.

---

Now we would like to add a UI using GWT.

My question is

**Can I include GWT directly into my current application, as a whole?**

I mean, my current Java application start from `main()`. On client side, we just execute `java Application` (simply say). After we have our GWT part, we really want everything still the same. On client side, we don't need to let client or we ourselves install many new things.

So ideally, after we finish our GWT part, for client, still, our application is one application and the way to launch is only `java Application`

We don't want to tell client that we need a TomCat server to be seperately installed.

We don't want client feel troublesome and it seems now we need to maintain multiple packages, etc.

Comment: Yeah sure you can do that. Your next question is of course going to be "how?", but that cannot be answered as long as you refuse to tell what this GWT application is actually going to do.

Comment: @Gimby what it does is give client a web site, and client choose some tables to view, and in the back, data is provided and presented to client

Comment: In other words it is pretty much isolated from what the other application does. Its just a view on some database and you don't need to hook the two applications up to each other at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need a web-server to serve you GWT application, orelse it can not communicate with local Java app. As you run GWT-compiled Javascript in a browser, it can't access to your local machine resources.

It can be a Tomcat running on localHost or you could use Google App Engine. You can't run a GWT app like a Java Swing application.

But relax... Tomcat is not that troublesome and does not require more package that what is already in it.

Comment: You can run GWT in httpd.. Tomcat or GlassFish is not required. If its just client-side GWT code, then that just needs a web server to serve it and a browser to view it

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the difference with what I wrote. Jack needs a server to serve the GWT-compiled Js.